# how to get textNode.parentNode id?

Tags: jquery, textnode, parent-node, parentid

I'm trying to write a simple CMS where user can add new paragraphs in contenteditable DIV. Also all paragraph's id's must be re-numbered. I was able to do that with jquery finishing up with this code:

```
<div class="wrap" contenteditable="true">
    <p class="paragraph" id="parg1" onclick="createNewP('parg1');">  
    Press ENTER at the end of text - works!</p>
    <p class="paragraph" id="parg2" onclick="createNewP('parg2');">  
    Press ENTER in the middle of text - pargId is undefined!</p>
</div>
<div class="showPargId">
    newpargId:<br />
</div>
```

js:

```
function createNewP(pargId){ 
    $('.paragraph').removeClass('active');
    $('#' + pargId).addClass('active');
}
$(function(){
    $('.wrap').keyup(function(event) {
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (keycode == '13') { //create new <p> by pressing ENTER and renumber all <p> id's
            $('.paragraph').removeClass('active');
            var pSum = $('.paragraph').length;
            var i = 1;
            if ( i < pSum ) {
                $('.paragraph').each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('id' , 'parg' + i).attr("onclick" , "createNewP('parg" + i + "');");
                    i++;                    
                });
            }
            var newpargId = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endContainer.id; // id of a new paragraph where the cursor is placed
            $('#' + newpargId).addClass('active');
            $(function(){
                $('.showPargId').append(newpargId + '<br />');                
            });
        } else { //do nothing
        }
    });
});
```

Everything works great except window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endContainer.id; It gives me id of a parent .paragraph only if the text cursor was placed at the end of the text in paragraph when ENTER was pressed. But if cursor is placed in the middle of the text then "newpargId" id undefined.

You can check it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kacpaa/uGuhz/8/)

Is there any method to get textNode parent ID? like:

```
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).parent().attr('id');
```

I was trying:

```
$((newpargId).parentNode.id);
```

But it doesn't work :(

Comment: Why do all the paragraphs have to have `id`s in the first place? (Just curious.)

Comment: I need them for later (with the id of paragraph I will be displaying toolbar to edit text in this particular paragraph and the toolbar will have id="pargIDtoolbar").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) for that:

```
$(window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endContainer).closest("[id]").attr("id");
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uGuhz/10/)

`closest` finds the first element matching the given selector, starting with the current element and then looking at ancestors. The selector `[id]` matches an element that has an `id` attribute.

Or if for some reason you want to do it without jQuery:

```
var parent = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endContainer;
var newpargId = parent.id;
while (!newpargId && parent && parent.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== "BODY") {
    parent = parent.parentNode;
    newpargId = parent.id;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uGuhz/11/)